# How to change tire price when qty change event in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tierprice, qty, change

I want to change tier price on change Qty.If i have change Qty automatically tier price change.

Please Help How to achieve this,

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score -1):

Edit the product, under price, click on Advanced Pricing.

Under "customer group price" click on the add button.

choose all websites and all groups (or whichever groups you want the rule applied to), and then add the quantity where you want the rule to kick in and the amount that you want the discount to be

Comment: Why downvoting? This does exactly what you want